# MySQL query with where statement with varchar field

Tags: mysql

I have column ProjectTab and its value is: 8,10,12,14 (varchar) - it can be assigned to multiple tabs.
Is there a way to make where statement to say search all where ProjectTab = 10?
I tried this but not working:

```
SELECT * FROM `ProjectTabs`
WHERE ProjectTab IN (10)
```

Like operator is not the answer. It could be but my field must be ,8,10,12,14, and the operator should be like this WHERE ProjectTab LIKE '%,10,%'
I think that this sucks..
Please, help.

Comment: Does this work for you?  

    SELECT * FROM `ProjectTabs`
    WHERE ProjectTab IN ('10', '12')

Comment: It does suck because jamming comma-separated lists into a relational database is bad design.

Comment: You should look into database normalization. That is how you correctly deal with this design problem

Comment: No, this is the same as mine just added 12. The problem is that this is string (8,10,12,14). 
Other record could be with value (5,6,10).
I need all which have 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is bad design and you should consider refactoring this, MySQL will dig you out of this hole with [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM `ProjectTabs`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10', ProjectTab );
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/045d1/1

Comment: Thank you this is working fine for me.
I realize that comma-separated lists is bad design but I inherited that project and for now I can not do anything else.
Thank you.